# Sklearn custom transformers: difference between using FunctionTransformer and subclassing TransformerMixin

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

In order to do proper CV it is advisable to use pipelines so that same transformations can be applied to each fold in the CV. I can define custom  transformations by using either `sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTrasformer` or by `subclassing sklearn.base.TransformerMixin`. Which one is the recommended approach? Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well it is totally upto you, both will achieve the same results more or less, only the way you write the code differs.

For instance, while using `sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer` you can simply define the function you want to use and call it directly like this ([code from official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-function-transformer-py))

```
def all_but_first_column(X):
    return X[:, 1:]

def drop_first_component(X, y):
    """
    Create a pipeline with PCA and the column selector and use it to
    transform the dataset.
    """
    pipeline = make_pipeline(PCA(), FunctionTransformer(all_but_first_column),)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
    pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return pipeline.transform(X_test), y_test
```

On the other hand, while using `subclassing sklearn.base.TransformerMixin` you will have to define the whole class along with the `fit` and `transform` functions of the class.
So you will have to create a class like this(Example code take from [this blog post](https://dreisbach.us/articles/building-scikit-learn-compatible-transformers/))

```
class FunctionFeaturizer(TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, *featurizers):
        self.featurizers = featurizers

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        #Do transformations and return
        return transformed_data
```

So as you can see, `TransformerMixin` gives you more flexibility as compared to FunctionTransformer with regard to transform function. You can apply multiple trasnformations, or partial transformation depending on the value, etc. An example can be like, for the first 50 values you want to log while for the next 50 values you wish to take inverse log and so on. You can easily define your transform method to deal with data selectively.

If you just want to directly use a function as it is, use `sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTrasformer`, else if you want to do more modification or say complex transformations, I would suggest `subclassing sklearn.base.TransformerMixin`

Here, take a look at the following links to get a more better idea

- [handling unknown categories in sklearn](https://blog.pursuitofzen.com/categorygrouper-handling-unknown-categories-for-scikit-learn/)
- [Building sklearn compatible transformer](https://dreisbach.us/articles/building-scikit-learn-compatible-transformers/)
- [official documentation example of function transformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-function-transformer-py)

Comment: Don't you have to inherit from both `BaseEstimator` and  `TransformerMixin` to make `FunctionFeaturizer` work properly?

Answer (score 13):

The key difference between `FunctionTransformer` and a subclass of `TransformerMixin` is that with the latter, you have the possibility that your custom transformer can learn by applying the `fit` method.

E.g. the `StandardScaler` learns the means and standard deviations of the columns during the `fit` method, and in the `transform` method these attributes are used for transformation. This cannot be achieved by a simple `FunctionTransformer`, at least not in a canonical way as you have to pass the train set somehow.

This possibility to learn is in fact the reason to use custom transformers and pipelines - if you just apply an ordinary function by the usage of a `FunctionTransformer`, nothing is gained in the cross validation process. It makes no difference whether you transform before the cross validation once or in each step of the cross validation (except that the latter will take more time).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `FunctionTransformer` is only indicated for stateless transformations.